# android draw animation under view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I have hierarchy:

```
Buttons  (Button childs)
   myView (View child)
      RelativeView (has background image)
```

in myView I draw circles those have animation (scales 0.5 to 1.0 size) , it has very low perfomance (draws very slowly)

I cant use surfaceview because surfaceview can't be transparent under any view, if it would be
transparent it has to be  `surface.setZOrderOnTop(true);`

what to do?

P.S.

drawing code

```
    // Square is Button that need to has animated circle under it
for (int i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++) {
        Square square = squares.get(i);
        if (square.animIndex == -1)
            continue;
        int left = square.getLeft();
        int top = getRelativeTop(square);

        int w = (int) (square.animIndex * square.getMeasuredWidth() * 4 / 10f);

        square.animIndex++;

        if (square.animIndex > 10) {
            square.animIndex = -1;
        }
              //note is circle bitmap
        c.drawBitmap(note, null, new Rect(left - w / 2 + square.getMeasuredWidth() / 2, top - w / 2
                + square.getMeasuredHeight() / 2, left - w / 2 + square.getMeasuredWidth() / 2 + w, top
                - w / 2 + square.getMeasuredHeight() / 2 + w), null);
    }
```

Comment: How are you drawing your circles? Can you post your code?

Comment: Where are you carrying out the for-next loop? Please also post your onDraw() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your full code it's hard to see what could be the cause of the bottle neck and it's not too clear from your question what you're trying to draw exactly so I can only give you some pointers.

If the code you posted is the `onDraw()` method then I would consider moving all calculations OUT and into another background thread. Because `onDraw()` is executed in the main (GUI) thread you should do as **little** computation as possible i.e. your bitmaps should just be ready to dump to screen and any parameters should be made available as variables i.e. don't go calling `getMeasuredHeight()` in `onDraw()`.

Also you're doing a cast:

> int w = (int) (square.animIndex * square.getMeasuredWidth() * 4 / 10f);

Avoid mixing floats and integers if you can but again, get this calculation out of the onDraw() method.

Fianlly as 'onDraw()` runs in the main thread it is imperative that you do not 'hog' the thread with computations. It will result in your app being unresponsive/sluggish and consequently your users will uninstall. There's probably nothing wrong with what you're trying to draw it's just **how** you're going about it that's causing the problem.